# How would I simplifiy this fraction with exponents?

Tags: exponential-function

How would I simplify this:

$$
\frac{\eta^{k-2}}{\eta_c^k}
$$

so that $\eta_c$ can also be raised to the power of $k-2$?

Would there be an $\eta_c^2$ on the top or bottom?

Answer (score 3):

You could simplify it as:

$$\left(\frac{\eta}{\eta_c} \right)^{k-2}\cdot\frac{1}{\eta_c^2}$$

In other words, it would go at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that $\eta_c^2$ is going to be on the bottom. Given your problem statement, the solution is baby-simple:

$$
\frac{\eta^{k-2}}{\eta_c^k}=\frac{\eta^{k-2}}{\eta_c^{k-2+2}}=\frac{\eta^{k-2}}{\eta_c^{k-2}\cdot\eta_c^2}
$$

If you want to move $\eta_c^2$ to the top, here are the steps to do that:

$$
\frac{\eta^{k-2}}{\eta_c^{k-2}\cdot\eta_c^2}=\frac{\eta^{k-2}}{\eta_c^{k-2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\eta_c^2}=\frac{\eta^{k-2}}{\eta_c^{k-2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\eta_c^{-(-2)}}=\frac{\eta^{k-2}}{\eta_c^{k-2}}\cdot\eta_c^{-2}=\frac{\eta^{k-2}\cdot\eta_c^{-2}}{\eta_c^{k-2}}
$$